# How to import file excel xlsx to laravel 8

Tags: excel, laravel, import

How to import file excel with format xlsx to Laravel 8?

I want import an excel file, i success for get data from excel. But when i run query for add data, the value is null.

I have code for import excel like this

Controller

```
Excel::import(new ImportItem($request->id_warrent), $request->upload);
```

Import

```
class ImportItem implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow, WithStartRow
    {
    
        public function  __construct($id_warrent)
        {
            $this->id_warrent   = $id_warrent;
        }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new WarrentItemModel([
            'id_warrent_item'      => Str::random(5),
            'warrent_entry_id'     => $this->id_warrent,
            'warr_item_category'   => $row[0],
            'warr_item_code'       => $row[1],
            'warr_item_nup'        => $row[2],
            'warr_item_name'       => $row[3],
            'warr_item_type'       => $row[4],
            'warr_item_qty'        => $row[5],
            'warr_item_unit'       => $row[6]
        ]);

    }


    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I don't know error position, when i tes $row used dd, i can get data from excel, but when i return new warrent item model, $row can't get value.

[test used dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6fgl.png)

[error can't get value from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtBFE.png)

Comment: add an image or details of your excel file

Comment: error says that u send null value to not nullable database field

Comment: if this video help you please set my comment useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMhjpRLq76I

Answer (score 0):

In your sql table you have you have a column 'warr_item_category', which default property is set to be not null, just set the property of that column to null and it will solve your problem, hope that helps